# My hands becoming fat due to weight lifting

Tags: workout

this is very undesirable result of lifting heavy weights. i don't want my fingers and palm to look like a balloon. It is even making even holding a pen difficult.

what can i do to stop this fattening of hand and specially fingers. I don't want this. It makes my hand look ugly, and make daily tasks annoying.

Would wearing glove solve this somehow. or they are for palms only.

Comment: Do you mean that you are developing [calluses](http://www.fitocracy.com/knowledge/how-to-deal-with-calluses-on-your-hands/)?

Comment: How heavy do you lift for various lifts? How big are your hands getting? Can you post a photo?

Comment: @kate that too but not as much of a problem. The whole thing goes down a little bit after no workout of 2 weeks. It's like swelling that stays, happens only after i go like above 50 pounds, and i go upto 85 pounds. It happens with machines also, in fact the main source, on machines i go like 290 pounds of push and pull.

Comment: In your [other question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14685/how-to-not-over-eat-and-still-not-feel-desperately-hungry) you mention weight loss and that you are eating "twice as much as you should be". Is your weight a potential problem causing swelling? While its possible weightlifting might be causing this we'd need to know *exactly* how much you are lifting for a *specific* lift to help - eg. X kg bench press or Y kg overhead press, not just "50 pounds".

Comment: My weight is not causing the swelling of hands. it was never issue and becomes a non issue once i stop going to gym for a month or start playing sports instead like bball. But as soon as i get serious my hands start getting puffy and i have a feeling they dont go back at being completely normal even during time i am not going. Condition improves though very much. I am not asking for advice on my workout routine i just want to know what can be done make my hands not swell if i want to life heavy weights. I asked around in gym they said that's a good thing it makes you look like a man. lol.

Comment: this is why i guess i focus more on abs, legs, back, and avoid arms. But i feel i need to do arms.

Answer (score 2):

The Mayo Clinic has [an article](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/hand-swelling/AN01403) on the topic from Dr. Edward R. Laskowski, M.D. that goes over the possible cause:

> Hand swelling during exercise is a fairly common problem. The cause
>   isn't completely clear, but hand swelling appears to be a result of
>   the way your body and blood vessels respond to the increased energy
>   demands of your muscles during exercise.

A possible remedy is proposed by [this article](http://www.realsimple.com/health/fitness-exercise/workouts/swollen-hands-00100000068850/) on Real Simple, though aimed at joggers, it may apply to you - do the hand exercises between sets:

> “Raising your arms over-head and pumping your fists can help keep
>   blood flowing as you jog,” says Sosena Kebede, an assistant professor
>   of medicine at Johns Hopkins University School of Medicine, in
>   Baltimore.

However, both articles indicate the swelling should go away a few hours, not days, after you've stopped exercising. This may be something you'd want to discuss with a healthcare professional.